Where/How can I find a specific proof from Wikipedia in a book/article etc.?
I‘m currently writing my Bachelor Thesis about the singular value decomposition and I want to include the Eckart-Young theorem for the spectral norm, the proof of which can be found on Wikipedia.
My problem is that I want to cite this proof but I don‘t believe I can give Wikipedia as a reference. So now I want to find this particular proof, or a similar one, in a book/paper/article or similar, so I can cite it properly.
I also din‘t find any in the References paragraph at the bottom of the page.
Does anyone know where to find such a reference or can tell me how to find it myself? Or is there a better solution to all of this?


You can always use google scolar. to look for literature. Maybe use the original https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/eckart&young.1936.pdf


Thank you trula for your answer. I already tried using Google Scholar, but to no success. I also read the original, which unfortunately is not fitting for my bachelor thesis.
